# Knowing where op structs are filled

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am currently trying to write a linux driver and for this it is necessary that I understand some apis to make best use of them. Often I come across a pattern where I start digging into a funciton and end up at a point where the function reads:

```
returnType OperationX(args...) {
    ...
    struct operations_t operations = get_operations();
    if(operations->X)
        return operations->X(args...)

}
```

Basically get_operations() returns a pointer to a global struct, which holds a pointer to the actual function running the operation.

I find it very tedious using the [linux cross reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com) to dig into the different places and then actually understand which assignement actually takes place. Is there a better faster way?

AN example would be [dma mapping](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/dma-mapping-common.h#L59).

Comment: Welcome to the world of Linux Kernel development :) .. I developed a USB driver for some embedded project I was working on about 2 years ago (and doubt much has changed in the way of documentation), and required the same thing (digging into areas of the kernel to ensure structures and data were passed properly). The 'faster' way I did it was to grab a copy of the kernel I was developing my driver for and use `grep/sed/awk/vi` to get a flow of the areas I was working in on the kernel. It's not exceedingly efficient but I gained a wealth of knowledge on the inner workings of the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git grep` and cscope are your best friends.

By the way, DMA operations are filled either by platform code or in IOMMU implementations. I bet most probably you have lib/swiotlb.c in use for that.