# Linux Streaming DMA ReMapping without Unmapping

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have noticed that the signature of [`pci_unmap_sg`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/dma-mapping-common.h#L59)(I show `dma_unmap_sg_attrs`, which is called by `pci_unmap_sg` through two macros and has clear parameter naming) includes the direction and attributes.

```
static inline void dma_unmap_sg_attrs(
   struct device *dev,
   struct scatterlist *sg, 
   int nents,
   enum dma_data_direction dir, 
   struct dma_attrs *attrs)
```

I wonder why it is necessary to know about the direction and attributes for unmapping. Initially i thought mapping was a bit like `malloc` and `free`. But seeing this I wonder if something like the following is legal:

```
dma_map_sg_attrs(..., dir=DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL,...);
...
dma_unmap_sg_attrs(..., dir=DMA_FROM_DEVICE ,...);
//continue use in TO_DEVICE direction
```

or

```
dma_map_sg_attrs(..., dir=DMA_TO_DEVICE,...);
...
dma_map_sg_attrs(..., dir=DMA_FROM_DEVICE ,...);
//start bidirectional use
```

Also can I do this (stream data via DMA from one device to the other if they cant directly dma each other):

```
dma_map_sg_attrs(dev1, ..., dir=DMA_FROM_DEVICE ,...);
dma_map_sg_attrs(dev2, ..., dir=DMA_TO_DEVICE ,...);
```

I tried digging into the function, but ended at `get_dma_ops` which gets function pointers from a global. But how to follow this code further is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006154/knowing-where-op-structs-are-filled)

---

### Update

I find the synchronization api even more confusing:

```
pci_dma_sync_sg_for_cpu(
  struct pci_dev *hwdev,
  struct scatterlist *sg,
  int nelems,
  int direction
)
```

What is the reason for this api to know the direction? Is there no way for the api to remember the original mapping direction and is it thus to eleminate `sync_for_cpu` if we mapped as `DMA_TO_DEVICE` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be simple and robust simultaneously. It depends how deep you know the CPU architecture you are using. The problem with DMA is CPU caches. CPU cache has to be coherent for DMA. Thus, we have different directions in the sync API since we may *access* data from both sides DMA and CPU. And like you know already the sync API is a cause of direction parameter in the map API.

P.S. It's not anyhow the comprehensive answer. For that you have to go through specific literature and documentation. I suggest you to start with `Documentation/DMA*.txt` files.

Comment: I read the `documentation/DMA` however, there are a few things left unclear, I also read ldd3, however that still refers to special functions for DAC which have been removed (I can't find them in lxr or the pci-dma headers). I am somewhat aware of the cache coherency problem, but thought the direction is sort of implicit if I sync for the device (FLush the cash to ram)/ for the cpu (invalidate cashlines for the area). I must have overlooked the part where they talk about mapping a buffer to multiple devices (see the last snippet before the update).

Comment: I cant find any notion of this in [DMA-API-HOWTO](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) and it is quite interesting since I consider mapping the memory for devA and devB and then issuing reads/writes to both devices faster, than remapping every time inbetween, this is what the question is about. Also I hoped the api would help me to program as architecture independent as possible. I am really sorry for sounding like a smart ass, but I prefer to know that my code is correct over, I tried it and it works (now in my particular case).

Comment: The actual answer was in the DMA-ATTR.txt under `DMA_ATTR_SKIP_CPU_SYNC` see my additional answer

Answer (score 0):

The tipps from Andy were right, while I thought that most of the DMA_ATTR_* wont help me since my device does the ordering so there is no way for the kernel to handle some of them, however if you look at `DMA_ATTR_SKIP_SYNC_CPU` you find (from [DMA-attributes.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/DMA-attributes.txt)):

```
 71 DMA_ATTR_SKIP_CPU_SYNC
 72 ----------------------
 73 
 74 By default dma_map_{single,page,sg} functions family transfer a given
 75 buffer from CPU domain to device domain. Some advanced use cases might
 76 require sharing a buffer between more than one device. This requires
 77 having a mapping created separately for each device and is usually
 78 performed by calling dma_map_{single,page,sg} function more than once
 79 for the given buffer with device pointer to each device taking part in
 80 the buffer sharing. The first call transfers a buffer from 'CPU' domain
 81 to 'device' domain, what synchronizes CPU caches for the given region
 82 (usually it means that the cache has been flushed or invalidated
 83 depending on the dma direction). However, next calls to
 84 dma_map_{single,page,sg}() for other devices will perform exactly the
 85 same synchronization operation on the CPU cache. CPU cache synchronization
 86 might be a time consuming operation, especially if the buffers are
 87 large, so it is highly recommended to avoid it if possible.
 88 DMA_ATTR_SKIP_CPU_SYNC allows platform code to skip synchronization of
 89 the CPU cache for the given buffer assuming that it has been already
 90 transferred to 'device' domain. This attribute can be also used for
 91 dma_unmap_{single,page,sg} functions family to force buffer to stay in
 92 device domain after releasing a mapping for it. Use this attribute with
 93 care!
```